# Cannot catch NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've seen quite a few threads on this topic, however I didn't find an answer for my question. I managed to solve my general issue, but I'd like to understand why my first attempts didn't work.

I have a class that is supposed to wait until an element with a specified class appears.

Here's the original code:

```cs
void Wait(string className)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
    {
        PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
    };
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.ClassName(className)));
}
```

Even though I used `wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));`, the `NoSuchElementException` exception is being thrown anyway on the line `wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.ClassName(className)));`.

My second attempt was this:

```cs
void Wait(string className)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
    {
        PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
    };
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    
    try
    {
        wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.ClassName(className)));
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException) {}
}
```

Again, the same line throws the exception, even though it's inside of `try-catch`. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

My final code looks as follows and it works:

```cs
void Wait(string className)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
    {
        PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
    };
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    
    wait.Until(drv =>
    {
        try
        {
            return drv.FindElement(By.ClassName(className));
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException) { }

        return null;
    });
}
```

I'm catching an exception inside of the lambda function.

The things that I don't understand:

1. In the first approach, why the `IgnoreExceptionTypes` method doesn't work?
2. In the second approach, why isn't the exception caught? Doens't it "bubble up" from lambda where it's originally thrown?

Comment: Have you thought about throwing `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) `Until` will *throws an exception that is not in the list of ignored exception types*. As I can see you have registered `NoSuchElementException` as ignored.

Comment: @PeterCsala Exactly, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mnj If it is listed inside the ignore exception types then `Until` will not throw that exception. So, then why do you expect to throw that?

Comment: @PeterCsala I think you misunderstood. In the post I said "Even though I used `wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));`, the `NoSuchElementException` exception is being thrown anyway on the line `wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.ClassName(className)));`." So, the thing is that I don't want the exception to be thrown, but it does throw.

Comment: @mnj Ohh apologise, you are right.

Comment: @mnj Based on screenshot it looks like the provided delegate throws this exception, not the `Until`. So the debugger stops there but the `Until` might swallow it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching `NoSuchElementException` try catching explicitly `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException` since there are more than one `NoSuchElementException` exception in C# (and in Java)

Comment: @Propher, I even already tried catching `Exception` - it doesn't work with attempts 1/2.

Comment: Maybe because you are missing an exception object there? Instead of `catch(Exception) { }` can you try `catch(Exception e) { }` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, both forms are acceptable. The one I used is the proper form if you don't need to access the exception object (and I don't need that). I checked that anyway as a sanity check, still fails.

Comment: OK.. When you finally get a solution for this problem please let me know, it's interesting. I can't do it myself since I have no C# with selenium on my computer. Only Java and Python.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, see code below. Also found this useful article: [article](https://7thzero.com/blog/selenium-wait-c)

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(numberOfSeconds));
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException));
        return wait.Until(d => {
            try
            {
                return d.FindElement(by);
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        });
```